# ssh and execute interactive command

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, batch

I currently have a process where i login to a machine, need to `ssh` to another machine and then run a command for an interactive job (on a queue-ing system). Is there a way to do this all in one shot?

Right now:

```
ssh my_machine
srun --pty R
```

I would to do this:

```
ssh my_machine "srun --pty R"
```

However this returns some errors:

```
 stty: standard input: Invalid argument
 srun: error: Not using a pseudo-terminal, disregarding --pty option
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate a pseudo-tty to your ssh session for the `srun` command.

Try this:

```
ssh -t my_machine "srun --pty r"
```

Comment: could you explain what a pseudo-tty is please?

Comment: tty is an abbreviation for terminal. Back in the day a terminal was essentially a monitor with a keyboard that interacted with a server through a serial connection. A pseudo-tty was invented in order to provide the same functionality for workstations that were remotely connected. Essentially any interaction you do with the shell in a modern system is done through a pseudo-tty. Running a remote command through an ssh connection will not, by default, allocate a pseudo-tty so the `-t` switch is added in order to force it.